# Calling a POST Method from C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, xamarin.android

i have an MVC web API with this method in my Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public void InsertSomething([FromBody] List<MyClass> newList)
{
    ...
}
```

MyClass: 
This class, it's the same in the Android project as in the WebAPI Project. They have the same attributes, types and names.

```
public class MyClass
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

I want to call it from my code but i don't know how. I'm using xamarin Android.

This is my try of code:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
List<MyClass> newList = new List<MyClass>();
newList.Add(new MyClass(){ Id = 5, Name = "test1"});
newList.Add(new MyClass(){ Id = 8, Name = "test2"});
string url = "http://localhost:57750/api/ControllerName/InsertSomething";
var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(newList),Encoding.UTF8,"application/json");
var result = client.PostAsync(url, content);
```

The problem is that my code isn't calling to the web method.

When i debug the code, when client.PostAsync is called, the app just stay waiting. No exception is throwed.

Some idea please?

Thanks!

PS: Sorry my bad english xd

Comment: Maybe `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new {test="test123",newList=newList })`

Comment: Thanks! I modify my code but isn't calling the webmethod yet :C

Comment: Beware that mvc web api has a limitation on reading parameters FromBody https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api

Comment: @GonzaloBustamante, Provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I don't have time to test this for a real answer - but I did notice you're awaiting a void. Also, you should get *something* back in result, like "NotFound" with details, or something... Nothing should never happen. Set the timeout to like 3 seconds or something to verify.

Comment: the default timeout for `HttpClient` is 100 seconds so if you arent receiving a timeout after 100 seconds then the issue is definitely on your end with how you're making the request. That wasn't so much of an answer- just trying to help you narrow things down... also I would try to use a tool like Fiddler to issue the post to ensure youre formatting the request json correctly

Answer (score -1):

The method client.PostAsync returns a Task which result you should await by using [async await pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh191443(vs.110).aspx):

```
var result1 = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
```

or .Result call as below:

```
var result2 = client.PostAsync(url, content).Result;
```

It may happen that the program will exit before HttpClient makes a request, you should explicitly wait for the result of the call.

Comment: `client.PostAsync(url, content)` starts the task. *await* it or not. it is being executed somewhere..

Comment: @GonzaloBustamante do you get any error? Can you put a breakpoint after a line with .Result and tell me if it's being met? Can you check in fiddler if the request is made?

Comment: @MichałŻołnieruk i don't get any error. When the debugger just execute client.PostAsync(url, content), the app do nothing, i mean, the execution doesn't continue neither throws an exception :C

Comment: Please use fiddler and verify if the request is even made from your machine to the server.